# postgres select latest record per entity except on field value

Tags: postgresql

I have a log table that looks something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
| id | company | type  | date_created |notes|
---------------------------------------------
| 1  |   co1   |       |  2016-06-30  | ... |
| 2  |   co2   | ERROR |  2016-06-30  | ... |
| 3  |   co1   |       |  2016-06-29  | ... |
| 4  |   co2   |       |  2016-06-29  | ... |
```

I have the following which selects the latest record per entity:

```
SELECT * 
FROM import_data_log a 
JOIN (SELECT company, max(date_created) date_created
        FROM import_data_log
      GROUP BY company) b
ON a.company = b.company AND a.date_created = b.date_created
```

which gives the result:

```
| 1  |   co1   |       |  2016-06-30  | ... |
| 2  |   co2   | ERROR |  2016-06-30  | ... |
```

I need to add a condition that does not select the entry with **type = ERROR** and get the next highest date for that company, so it would give:

```
| 1  |   co1   |       |  2016-06-30  | ... |
| 4  |   co2   |       |  2016-06-29  | ... |
```

Any ideas? It's probably something simple but for the life of me I can't seem to get it to work.

---

**UPDATE / FIX:**
Ok so after a lot of hair pulling, for anyone running into this issue, apparently Postgres doesn't compare null fields with anything, so it completely ignores all rows with type = null.

The way I fixed it is this, there is probably a nicer solution out there but for now this works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM import_data_log a 
JOIN (SELECT company, max(date_created) date_created
        FROM import_data_log
        WHERE (type <> 'ERROR' OR type is null)
      GROUP BY company) b
ON a.company = b.company AND a.date_created = b.date_created
```

Comment: I've changed my query for your requirement  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Query

```
SELECT id,company,type,max(date_created),notes 
FROM import_data_log
WHERE type != 'ERROR'
GROUP BY company
```

Comment: This gives zero results for some reason.

Comment: now I get the: ERROR:  column "import_data_log.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT id,company,type,max(date_created),notes

Comment: it is due to the sql_mode you have in your database engine, set it to '' none using           set sql_mode = ''    and then hit the query @Mankind1023

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct on (company) *
from import_data_log
where type is distinct from 'ERROR'
order by company, date_created desc
```

Check [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) and [`is [not] distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html):

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying "unknown"), not true or false, when either input is null. For example, 7 = NULL yields null, as does 7 <> NULL. When this behavior is not suitable, use the IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM constructs

Comment: I originally got my code from a post here on SO and they had distinct options, but someone mentioned that this is much faster on larger tables than distinct. This also gives zero results for some reason. If I remove the where it gives the 2 standard results. I've confirmed the table has fields where type is empty / not ERROR.

Comment: @Mankind1023 I changed the comparison operator to [`is distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) in case `type` can be `null`

Comment: So this didn't work either, but it did give me an idea to use (WHERE (type <> 'ERROR' OR type is null) in my code, which worked.